# Does android app bundle and proguard rules do the same optimization?

Tags: android, proguard, android-app-bundle

Is there any difference between proguard rules optimization and app bundle optimization or is it same thing? Can any one explain how they are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload **app bundle** to play store ,the play store will generate a new apk based on the user device , suppose user device is xhdpi , the generated apk by play store will only have xhdpi resources . This will not remove unused code .

Where as the **proguard** will remove all the unused code while generating the apk . It will not remove alternative resolution resources .

Comment: The purpose of both is not the same, appbundle reduces the download size of the app by generating multiple apks for different cpu architectures, screensizes, etc. But proguard or R8 not only shrink the resulting file size, also optimizes your code (makes your app faster) and obfuscates (this process also shrinks the file and make harder reverse engineering of your app)

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of this process is completely different.
An **Android app bundle** is an alternative application distribution format for Android. This is just like building an apk (older application distribution format).

And **Proguard** is free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. The purpose of using Progaurd is,

1. Shrinking – detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and
   attributes.
2. Optimization – analyzes and optimizes the bytecode of
   the methods.
3. Obfuscation – renames the remaining classes, fields,
   and methods using short meaningless names.

Comment: but app bundle also shrinks the app i wanted to know does app bundle shrinks, optimizes or obfuscate the classes, field and methods?

Comment: No, the bundling process does not obfuscate at all.